# How to hide the "Google" link on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api v3..How can I hide the "Google" link in the bottom corner of my Google map (circled below)?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [terms of use](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms).  That is not allowed (at least with any of the free services).  I think this is the relevant section, but it is your responsibility to read, understand and abide by the terms if you are using the service.

**9.4 Attribution.**

(a) Content provided to you through the Service may contain the trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features of Google, its partners, or other third party rights holders of content indexed by Google. When Google provides this attribution, you must display it as provided through the Service or as described in the Maps APIs Documentation and may not delete or in any manner alter these trade names, trademarks, service marks, logos, domain names, and other distinctive brand features.

Comment: Although this is not allowed, for the purpose of technical education it would be nice to know how to deal with the issue